# My Imagick code never seems to resize and still produce a sharp image

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagick, lossless-compression

I fear that Imagick may not support sharp image resizing. Even the best filters are returning blurry results which are sub par, even horrible in my humble opinion.

This is the BEST quality I can get out of Imagick:
[image: Imagick]

This is resized using [TimThumbs](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/):
[image: TimThumbs]

NOTICE the drastic quality difference? Can anyone provide an example of a sharp image being produced by Imagick?

Below is the Imagick code used to generate the first image:

```
function imgSize($imagePath,$imageName,$imageExt,$width,$height,$copy) {
    $file = "img/".$imageName."-".$width."x".$height.".".$imageExt;
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        try {
                $image = $imagePath;
                $im = new Imagick();
                $im->pingImage($image);
                $im->readImage($image);
                $im->setImageFormat($imageExt);
                //$im->thumbnailImage($width,$height,true);
                $im->cropThumbnailImage($width,$height);
                $im->resizeImage($width,$height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0,false);
                $im->cropThumbnailImage($width,$height);
                if ($imageExt=("jpg"||"JPG")) {
                    $img->setComression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
                    $img->setComressionQuality(100);
                }
                if (!$copy==null) {
                    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
                    $draw->setFont("fpdf/font/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
                    $draw->setFontSize(35);
                    $draw->setFillColor("Gray");
                    $draw->setFillAlpha(0.5);
                    $draw->setGravity(Imagick::INTERPOLATE_AVERAGE);
                    $im->annotateImage($draw,0,0,-45,$copy);
                }
                $im->writeImage("img/".$imageName."-".$width."x".$height.".".$imageExt);
                $im->destroy();
                return "img/".$imageName."-".$width."x".$height.".".$imageExt;
        }
        catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
    }
};
```

I am aware there are similar questions but there has not been a sufficient answer to this image quality problem. Most attempts to address Imagick's image quality issues are to reduced the problem to, "well that's what you get when you shrink an image." But the TimThumbs image example I have provided in this post disproves that assumption. You can shrink an image and get stunning results using PHP.

Comment: Before accusing Imagick of being at fault here, are you sure that your math for the aspect ration of the image is correct?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato if there is a problem I cannot see it. The code provided above seems to comply with the standards used by others on the Internet. I would be more than willing to accept the problem is my own. In fact I would prefer that so that I can get this fixed sooner. : )

Comment: Fair enough. Just checking. :)

Comment: Can we have a link to larger image, is GD any better ?

Comment: @BojanT yeah no problem. The following link is the image being processed by both Imagick and TimThumbs. 
http://chakinggallery.com/uploads/20140204-20140204-DSC07702--2.jpg

Comment: This might be helpful: [setCompression vs setImageCompression](https://xenforo.com/community/threads/wrong-methods-being-used-to-set-imagemagick-compression.34153/)

Answer (score 3):

This seems better to me, I just resized it 20% of original image. Using GD and 100% quality as JPEG

```
function resizeImg($filename, $percent, $saveTo) {

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $newwidth = $width * $percent;
    $newheight = $height * $percent;

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($thumb, $saveTo, 100);
    imagedestroy($thumb);
}

resizeImg('image.jpg', 0.2, 'image02.jpg');
```

[image: GD]

I have compiled php55-imagick extension to check your code , first of all you have misspelled  2 method names , when fixed  resulting image  is actually OK `setCompression` not `setComression`

```
$im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setCompressionQuality(100);
```

[image: Imagick]

Here is image with correct methods as showdev commented , doubling image size (121K vs 329K ) , but to me not much benefit

```
$im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
```

[image: Imagick using setImageCompression]

Comment: Interesting. I believe TimThumbs uses GD. If you don't mind me asking what was your GD code?

Comment: I see. Well I believe I am going to rewrite this for GD as it seems to produce better results than Imagick. However I wont mark this as the answer as it doesn't address Imagick directly but does make a compelling case that in the GD v. Imagick debate. It seems Imagick is deficient in the most important category, quality.

Comment: Did you read showdev's comment? You are not using the right function. Also check http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompressionquality.php#96836

Comment: @onetrickpony Confirmed using `setImageCompression` file size doubles (121K vs 329K ) though I cant visually see a difference in image quality, will edit a post to add second version

Comment: It's probably because you're calling cropThumbnailImage(), which may also scale the image. If you're doing the resizing yourself use cropImage()